# SpringBoot: Adding 3rd Party jars in a Spring Boot Project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have set MAVEN paths and variables. I am able to run a sample SpringBoot project in Eclipse but what I want is I have a custom jar and I am using classes from that jar in my Spring Boot Project. When I include this custom jar and build the SpringBoot application, I get the following errors

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
>   is no POM  in this directory (D:......\SpringBootDemo\target).
>
> Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help
>   1]
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you
>   specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this
>   directory (D:......\SpringBootDemo\target).
>
> Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

My POM.xml is as follows:

```
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBoot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SpringBootDemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Am I missing anything?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Error message is quite self explanatory: `Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory`. You invoked it in `target` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you will have 3rd party JARs that you need to put in your local repository for use in your builds, since they don't exist in any public repository like [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/). The JARs must be placed in the local repository in the correct place in order for it to be correctly picked up by Apache Maven. To make this easier, and less error prone, we have provide a goal in the [maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) which should make this relatively painless. To install a JAR in the local repository use the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

With version 2.5 of the maven-install-plugin it gets even better. If the JAR was built by Apache Maven, it'll contain a pom.xml in a subfolder of the META-INF directory, which will be read by default. In that case, all you need to do is:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

From a [Maven Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: I have some issue. But not solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449991/maven-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-omnesys-omne-om-omn/62450552?noredirect=1#comment110450773_62450552